# Why does invoking toObject() on a mongoose document delete a property when called with getters set to true?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When invoking `toObject()` on a document with a (nested) property which is set to `null`, the property will be erased but only when supplying the `getters` option with `true`, see example below.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
   customer: {
      name: { type: String, required: false },
   },
});

var Model = mongoose.model('Model', schema);
var model = new Model();
model.customer = null;
console.log(model.toObject());
console.log(model.toObject({ getters: true }));

//Prints: 
//{ _id: 58e00dcd71bf5916802bdb3c, customer: null }
//{ _id: 58e00dcd71bf5916802bdb3c, id: '58e00dcd71bf5916802bdb3c' }
```

Why is this?
I'm using mongoose v.4.9.2

Comment: The same code is printing the first line in both cases for me.  Using Mongoose 4.5.2

Comment: I'm using v.4.9.2

Comment: Same result with 4.9.2

Comment: That's very odd, I'm having the different print outs regardless of using version 4.5.2 or 4.9.2

Comment: @TalhaAwan My bad, I had `getter: true` and not `getters: true` (missing an 's') in the code example above which made it print the same output for both cases.